# Stop multiple processes in server

Tags: linux, cmd.exe, process

I run several processes in one server with ssh in cmd, so how to stop those processes in one time? And also avoid to log out this server?

Here is the command:

```
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.***.**.** 9001
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.***.**.** 9002
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.***.**.** 9003
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.***.**.** 9004
```

I use killall5 can finish all processes but it will log out the server at the same time...

Comment: What processes are you trying to kill? Show us the command you used!

Comment: And how did you try to kill them?

Comment: I need to finish them to test others ports, or just need to restart the process with same port, so I use killall5 , but it directly log out the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `killall5` for this purpose. The man page states

> Its primary (only) use is in the rc scripts found in the /etc/init.d directory

Instead you should use

```
killall java
```

to kill only processes with `java` in their name.

If there can be java-processes you don't want to kill you can use `pgrep -l [search pattern]` to get exactly those processes you want to kill (`-l` shows the process names too, not only the PIDs) and then use `pkill` with the same search pattern.

For instance

```
pgrep -l "fire|chrom"
```

gives (in my case) all `firefox` and `chromium` processes. And

```
pkill "chrom"
```

kills all my chromium-processes.